# Laravel Passport - How to hide client credentials in javascript?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am using angular 2 with laravel. I'm trying to install the passport of the laravel for create autentication. I want to do a simple authentication.

My system in gets a token and uses this token for calls to the server. However I read in the documentation that I need create one client_id, client_secret and grant_type.

I should use this information to get the token. My question is...

Is it necessary to hide this information in my javascript? (client_id, client_secret and grant_type).

How could I hide this information in javascript?

Comment: Is the angular app served by the laravel app on the same domain? [If so you don't have to expose your client credentials at all](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript)

Comment: I read this part of the documentation, but it was not clear to me. Using the CreateFreshApiToken in my server what do I need to do next? I will not need to send anymore the (client_id, client_secret and grant_type)?

Comment: You can only do use that if the Laravel and Angular are served on the same domain. It uses the authenticated session **instead of** a client_id/client_secret. If you use that it creates a token in the session to use, you just need to make sure to include the csrf token in the request.

Comment: I understood. In my case they are different domains. That means I'm going to have to use the client_id, client_secret e grant_type?

Comment: Another doubt is... You have to hide the client_id, client_secret e grant_type in my javascript?

Comment: In that case you will need to use a client. Those credentials shouldn't be exposed in the javascript, especially the client_secret. The best way would have a server side login script that your angular will give the users credentials to. That script will have the client credentials and use the given user credentials to request a token from your api and return it to the angular app

Comment: I understood. I found this tutorial. http://esbenp.github.io/2017/03/19/modern-rest-api-laravel-part-4/ seems to be good. I'll follow. thank you friend.

Comment: @jfadich How can I call a route within a controller? You know how I call the route /oauth/token on my controller?

Comment: @RenatoSouza that tutorial uses a library to do that but you can use what says here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#requesting-tokens .

Comment: May i also ask what kind of layer of security does hidding the token do? If there is just a proxy to login, what difference does it make by having it not go to client side? client side might not have client_secret but it also doesn't need it since it can just post to /loginProxyRoute right?